# simulating raw_input() in unittest module of python 2

Tags: python, unit-testing, input

I'm trying to understand how to use unittest framework of python

I have a piece of code that looks like this --

```
while True:
    filename = raw_input('Enter file')
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        break
    else:
        print "That file does not exist"
return filename
```

Can somebody help me out in developing the unittest module to test this. I'm asking this question in order to learn how to use unittesting (i'm trying to learn TTD: Test-Driven Development)

So far I've come up with this
...
import unittest
import os.path

class TestFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.prompt = 'Enter filename: '

def test_get_file(self):

    # TODO make sure empty filename argument requests for new filename
    filename = find_author.get_valid_filename(self.prompt)
    self.assertTrue(<EXPRESSION?>)

    # TODO make sure valid filename returns the "filename"
    # TODO make sure invalid filename prompts that file does not exit and requests new filename
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    unittest.main()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to monkey-patch `raw_input`.

For example, in your testing module (since you should split your testee and tester into separate files), you might have:

```
import module_being_tested
... run tests ...
```

Before you run your tests, you can simply do:

```
import module_being_tested

def mock_raw_input(s):
    return 'data.txt'

module_being_tested.raw_input = mock_raw_input

... run tests ....
```

Now, when your testee module calls `raw_input`, it will actually be calling `mock_raw_input`, and will always get `'data.txt'` back.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [vgel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20459380/185053) to this question, I had the need to simulate different consecutive inputs, so always returning the same string wasn't enough. This is how I solved it:

```
import module_being_tested

mock_raw_input_counter = 0
mock_raw_input_values = []
def mock_raw_input(s):
    global mock_raw_input_counter
    global mock_raw_input_values
    mock_raw_input_counter += 1
    return mock_raw_input_values[mock_raw_input_counter - 1]

module_being_tested.raw_input = mock_raw_input
```

Then in the test you want to use this multi-input capability:

```
def test_interactive_sequence_selection_dummy_2_99_0_Z_1(self):
    global mock_raw_input_counter
    global mock_raw_input_values
    mock_raw_input_counter = 0
    mock_raw_input_values = ["2", "99", "0", "Z", "1", ""]
    new_sequences = module_being_tested.interactive_sequence_selection(["A", "B", "C"], [None])
    self.assertEqual(new_sequences, ["C", "A", "B"])
```

That will simulate the entry of the following values:

```
2[ENTER]
99[ENTER]
0[ENTER]
Z[ENTER]
1[ENTER]
[ENTER] (no input, just pressing Enter)
```

(the code in `interactive_sequence_selection` uses a `while s != "":` loop to ask the user to input various values and terminate with an empty `Enter` press)